# Gnuplot misscalculating functions

Tags: math, gnuplot

Im trying to get Gnuplot to plot the function arctan(0.0199/(0.000415+x)).
My code is

```
f(x)=atan(0.0199/(0.000415+x))
plot f(x) title "stuff",
```

bur for some reason Gnuplot seems to be interpreting the part inside the brackets as a factor, visible in the fact that the arctan doesen't reach the expected maximum of pi/2. I have added the final below.
[The aformentioned Plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIBN1.png)

Comment: Also excuse the name, I just created this account using my google account and am not quite sure how to change it.

Comment: The WolframAlpha plot for comparison: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%5E(-1)(0.0199957%2F(0.000415897+%2B+x))&lk=1&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D

Comment: `set samples 10000`

Answer (score 0):

gnuplot is old! back in the day, monitor resolutions were much smaller. So, the default sampling rate was chosen to be 100. This means, whatever your xrange is, gnuplot will sample 100 points evenly distributed in your xrange. Many maxima and minima are missed because of this.

However, as @user8153 points out, `set samples 10000` to the rescue. gnuplot will now sample 10,000 x values in your xrange. 10000 is a good number but smaller will do. Experiment, at 5000, it looks like the function reached pi/2. At 1000 you can see it does not make it.

```
set yrange [0:2]
set samples 10000
f(x)=atan(0.0199/(0.000415+x))
plot f(x) title "stuff"
replot pi/2
```